# What does 'this.value' mean in Classic ASP Javascript reference?

Tags: javascript, asp-classic, this

I am trying to figure out what 'this.value' means in this Classic ASP reference.

```
Response.Write "<Select name=""TaskID" & tmprec.Fields("TaskID") & """ onChange=""javascript:IsTaskComplete(this.value," & num & ")"" class=""SelectText"" style=""width:100%"">" & vbCrLf &_"<Option value=""NULL""></Option>"
```

What exactly is is passing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Select name=""TaskID" & tmprec.Fields("TaskID") & """ onChange=""javascript:IsTaskComplete(this.value," & num & ")"" class=""SelectText"" style=""width:100%"">" & vbCrLf &_"<Option value=""NULL""></Option>
```

This refers to the element called, with other words the select-element and this.value is the value changed/chosen.

Read more at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#As_a_DOM_event_handler

Actually this is a very important concept in javascript and behaves a little differently than in other "traditional" object-oriented languages.